# How to configure Jenkins to build the branch I pushed to a bitbucket repository

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

My repository is Bitbucket. I use generic-webhook-trigger to trigger build on a specific branch, take the branch dev1 as an example. I created a Jenkins job. The "Branches to build" > "Branch Specifier" is dev1. I configured Bitbucket webhook. It triggers build in Jenkins on the branch dev1 whenever there is a "git push" to dev1 branch.

I would like to be able to trigger builds on any branches I git pushed. Developers create new branches while they are developing code. They prefer Jenkins can trigger builds on the branches they git pushed. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just leave the branch specifier as blank instead of setting it to `dev1`:

> Specify the branches if you'd like to track a specific branch in a repository. If left blank, all branches will be examined for changes and built.